# Removing NoData values from image in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, nodata

I would like to remove the No Data values of my image in ArcMap. The image has one band. I already tried different ways to do that, but at the end, the No Data values are still in black color. At least, outside the region the black color is removed , but the No Data inside the region is red. I tried the function SetNull and Con (from raster calculator), and reclassify.

[image: My image, original]

[image: after remove]

Comment: Single Con(isnull(a),any number, a) should do.

Comment: Its not clear want you want? Do you want to keep NODATA within your data or do you want to keep NODATA outside your data? On do you want to recode NODATA within your entire raster to some other value, if so what do you want?

Comment: I want to keep NODATA outside my data.

Comment: In this case convert to single polygon, remove holes, convert to raster and do Con calculation between 2 rasters.

Comment: Thank you FelixIP, I am going to try. Because there is something very strange, I have NODATA values, but when I am going to add white color to those pixels, they are with the minimum value, but only the NODATA pixels inside the area. NODATA pixels outside can be set to white. Anyway, I am just telling you what is happening, so I don't know if maybe I am doing something wrong or, I am doing well. At the end, as I perceived that the minimum values are equal to NODATA, I just set to white color.

Answer (score 1):

if just for visualisation, you can set (NoData) to no color:

1. Go to *layer properties* of raster.
2. Go to symbology menu.
3. Set (Display NoData as) no color.
   [image]
   [image]

---

or you can use [ArcScan](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm) tool.

Comment: I did that, and is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get rid of the NoData value from the output by adding a property called (data ignore value) to the header file, and I assigned it to 0.

data ignore value = 0

It worked for me so many times using ENVI 5.3